# Bitbucket error on pull: "Host is down", Bitbucket status shows all functioning as normal

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm working with a Bitbucket-hosted repository that has been working smoothly until now. Using SourceTree on Mac OS X. My last successful pull/push was 10 hours ago, and it went fine. Then I shut down my laptop. Started it up to get to work today and now, when I go to pull, I get the error:

`error: Failed to connect to 131.103.20.167: Host is down while accessing https://username@bitbucket.org/projectname/projectname.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed`

(where username is my username and projectname is my project name).

Searching combinations of this error in the Bitbucket KnowledgeBase hasn't gotten me very far. Checking the Bitbucket status page is showing that all services are up.

Can anyone glean from this error what path I should be investigating (a config file issue? A problem with authentication or protocols? A "free service is down, twiddle thumbs til service resumes" issue?)?

Comment: If i go to https:// That.Ip.Address, I see a bitbucket log-in screen. If I enter my credentials, I get right in and see my repositories. So that IP address is provably not down.

Answer (score 1):

LittleSnitch was the problem, shutting off Network Filter while I did the pull/push resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you get the error due to some issues on the side of the Bitbucket. So I guess that the only source to get the answer from is Bitbucket's support since the issue is specific to Bitbucket. Contact them.